# I can imagine him (being??) really angry

Tags: verbs, participles, present-participles

1. You could imagine sentence (a) (being??) uttered by someone consulting their diary and seeing that tomorrow's page is blank.
2. I can imagine him (being??) really angry.
3. I can't imagine elephants (being??) able to fly.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/imagine says the verb "imagine" is sometimes followed by the ing-form of another verb: *She **imagined** herself **sitting** in her favourite chair back home*. So my question is: do we need "being" in (1) (using the passive voice), (2) and (3) (both using an adjective)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- She imagined herself sitting on the bench and reading. Yes, it is an action verb.
- She imagined herself **being** rich. Yes, it is an adjective.

Now, do you "need" *being* with the adjective?

Let's just put it this way. It is more elegant as in English we'd talk about *being rich* or *being poor* or *being smart*, etc. So, in a sense, it is incomplete without it.

Now, in speech, you might drop it or for other literary reasons....

By the way, the verb **imagine** and **see** and work this way.

"He saw himself at the helm of a sailing vessel in the 15th century, but it was only a dream."